# how can i use pivot query in two tables i sql server2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

i want to use pivot query using two different table.
i have two table one is GPadvance and second one is GPexpenditure . 
i have given advance to gp and get the advance report form the gpadvance. second is whatever the expenduture done by gp it saved in gpexpenditure table. now i want to use pivot table accordingly to GP wise like
you can see the first one data is coming from gpadvance and second column is amount spent data is coming is gpexpenduture.

i want to use single query to use both table data if gp has spent money or not, 
iam using the following pivot table for the advance release

```
select * from
(
    select Unit_Name,gpname,isnull(amount,0)as amount,Mcomponent 
    from AdvGP_report 
    where unit_id='7' and year='2014-15' and quarter='4'
) as s
pivot
(
     sum(amount) for mcomponent in("1","2","3")
) as a
```

and second pivot query for amount spent is

```
(
   select isnull(financialtarget,0)as FT,MinorComponent_Id 
   from GPWDPMPR 
   where unitid='7' and mpryear='2014-15'
) as i
pivot
(
   sum(FT) for MinorComponent_Id in("19","4","8")
) as b
```

its giving the result but repeated many times the amount.

Comment: In which query you have the issue?

Comment: I want to add both query

Comment: Can you add expected output to the question?

Comment: Do you want this as a single result or multiple result. Its not clear from your question

Comment: The result would be how much advance i have given to GP in different heads  and how much  he spent in same head, result would be  in same row.  so that i am trying to use pivot table. i have tried the all join query but data is repeated many times.

Comment: We cannot guess the table structure and queries from your comments. Consider the situation where you want to find out a guy from a group of people by just knowing the name and no other hints